# Properties on atomic property are disappearing

Tags: ios, objective-c, atomic

I have a bunch of properties on my model object: `ModelObject` declared as follows:

`@property (atomic, strong, readonly) LotsOfProps *lotsOfProps;`

Inside this object there are properties like this:

```
LotsOfProps {
@property (nonatomic, strong) AProp prop;
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyProp myProp;
}
```

I do some navigation between different collectionViewCells each of which is backed by a model: `Model`. On first navigation the properties are present on `LotsOfProps` and when I navigate away and back to collection view backed-model and check the properties on `LotsOfProps` I see that they're all nil. I've declared encodeWithCoder, decodeWIthCoder on `Model` and `LotsOfProps` and from my understanding atomic already auto generates synchronize methods so even if it's accessed on different threads it should be thread safe.

Any ideas why all of the properties are nil on my object `LotsOfProps`? I've never seen an issue like this before hence if there's any more information I can provide please let me know!

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with `atomic`. It sounds like you just mean that when you "navigate back", this is a different LotsOfProps object. That's easy to confirm; just log it to the console and look at its memory address.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I'll check to see if that's the case

Comment: I can't easily confirm that this is the case as it's intermittent when the `LotsOfProps` has all of it's properties set to nil. Hence, why I thought it might be related to a race condition. In other words, sometimes when I navigate from the first cell and back all the properties are set to nil. Most of the time however, they are not. Once all the properties are set to nil though they stay that way for the lifecycle of the object.

Comment: Well, it might be related to a race condition. But that would have to do with bad multithreading code, not the fact that this thing is atomic. However, did you notice that in your question you didn't say _anything_ about what "navigate away and back to collection view backed-model" means, or show _anyI code?? So no one here has the slightest idea what you are doing. Basically, you have given no information at all. Therefore you just have to help yourself. I gave you a suggestion for doing that, but of course it is only a suggestion.

Comment: @MichaelGofron Where are you storing the data outside of the cell?   Cells in table views or collections are not intended to store model data directly.

Comment: Currently the data is stored in a controller that configures the cell. (Handles dequeue re-usable cell, etc.)